# Heat of Combustion, Vaporization tables

Tags: materials, thermodynamics, combustion

It's my first time posting on this specific forum. I hope I'm doing this right.

I am currently modeling fire spreading through different buildings via FDS, but I lack the properties of the materials modeled, such as heat of combustion and heat of vaporization. I've searched the internet for days and some information is still missing. And I'm not sure what to do.

Does any of you happen to know where I can find an extended combustion properties of materials table?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics